# IOS: From uitableview cell validate user send ridirect to respective Controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Hi friends my project is based on parsing json datas and displaying in screen. i have done parsing datas and every other stuffs. and am using storyboards in my project. now my problem is. I have a task where I need to authenticate for loading `viewController` on clicking from `tableViewCell`. `if row 6 has been clicked it has to check nsuserdefaults if its null its has ridriect to login page. if login success it has to load a recpective page of row 6`. As shown in above screen[image]

i cant able to load login screen on clicking tableviewcell when i click it shows this error:

```
2014-02-24 10:26:24.775 RT[751:c07] -[RTLoginViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8dc4510
2014-02-24 10:26:24.776 RT[751:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RTLoginViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8dc4510'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2513012 0x2338e7e 0x259e4bd 0x2502bbc 0x250294e 0x24d9e 0x607285 0x6074ed 0x10115b3 0x24d2376 0x24d1e06 0x24b9a82 0x24b8f44 0x24b8e1b 0x2f937e3 0x2f93668 0x557ffc 0x297d 0x28a5 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

I used this code to load LoginviewController onclicking  tableviewcell also am using navigationController

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(indexPath.section == 0) {

         if(indexPath.row == 8) {
            NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            if ([defaults objectForKey:@"firstname"] ==NULL  && [defaults objectForKey:@"lastname"]==NULL) {
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
            // Get instance of initial Viewcontroller from storyboard
            UINavigationController *navController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"login_id"];
            // Get instance of desired viewcontroller
            RTLoginViewController *viewController = navController.viewControllers[0];
            //viewController.kApiKey = apikey;
            //viewController.kSessionId = sessionid;
            //viewController.kToken = token;
            [self presentViewController:navController animated:NO completion:nil];

            }
        }
}
}
```

Please help me how to do it Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are calling `topViewController` method somewhere in `RTLoginViewController`, or thought the object of `RTLoginViewController`. It is named incorrectly somewhere in .h or doesn't exist.

Edit 1 :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"DetailGrandComptes"]) 
    {
       MyViewController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
        destination.a = 6 ;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Search topViewController in your project ..find where it exists and check if topViewController is there in topViewController? Make spelling correct or make it ok...